# split int and string to tuple from string python

Tags: python, split

i have a list of string with names and numbers like :

```
["mike5","john","sara2","bob","nick6"]
```

and i want to create from each string a tuple `(name,age)` like this :

```
[('mike', 5), ('john', 0), ('sara', 2), ('bob', 0), ('nick', 5)]
```

so if a string doesn't contain a number the age is 0

what is the simplest way to do it?

i tried to use :

```
temp = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)")
res = temp.match(type).group()
```

but it fails

Comment: "but it fails" is not a meaningful description of the error

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to find the name and the number `([a-z]+)(\d+)?`, along with `.groups(0)` as default value (see [`match.groups()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups))

```
def split_vals(word):
    name, number = re.search(r"([a-z]+)(\d+)?", word).groups(0)
    return name, int(number)

values = ["mike5", "john", "sara2", "bob", "nick6"]
values = [split_vals(value) for value in values]
# [('mike', 5), ('john', 0), ('sara', 2), ('bob', 0), ('nick', 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If fails because your match doesn't return anything:

```py
temp.match('john') is None
True
```

You need to change your regex to:

```py
# The * means 0 or more. Otherwise, you've required a number to be present
temp = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]*)")
temp.match('john')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='john'>
```

Last, if you want tuples, use `groups()`, not `group()`

```py
[temp.match(item).groups() for item in x]
[('mike', '5'), ('john', ''), ('sara', '2'), ('bob', ''), ('nick', '6')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

The regex is correct up to `[0-9]+`. This means you **MUST** match 1 or more digits. However, not all your strings will have a digit present such as `john`, so I would suggest using `*` which matches zero or more digits.

You are using the syntax `pattern.match(string)` which will throw an error. You need to use the syntax `match(pattern, string)` (see below for further clarification).

In addition, using `groups()` instead of `group()` will return a tuple of all the captured matches within your regex (again see below).

Using a loop to iterate over your items and an `if` statement you should be able to achieve your desired result:

```
lst=["mike5","john","sara2","bob","nick6"]
pattern = re.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]*)")
name_age = []
for value in lst: 
    name,age = re.match(pattern,value).groups()
    if not age: age = 0
    name_age.append((name,age))
print(name_age)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

inArr = ["mike5","john","sara2","bob","nick6"]
outArr = []

for item in inArr:
    regexResult = re.search('([a-z]+)(\d?)', item, re.IGNORECASE)
    if regexResult:
        name = regexResult.group(1)
        age = regexResult.group(2) or 0
        outArr.append((name, int(age))

print(outArr) # [('mike', 5), ('john', 0), ('sara', 2), ('bob', 0), ('nick', 6)]
```